# What should i do if i want to run C-a " upon starting screen?

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

I'm currently starting screen as part of my .bashrc, but i want the first thing that shows up to be the same thing as when you run `C-a "` when screen is already running. I know i could run `screen -ls` but that only lists the running sessions, it doesn't provide me with the same ui as `C-a "` does.

Comment: You received an answer, but the question might be more useful to others if you clarify what C-a is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to an existing screen session with `-x` or `-r`, you can include `-p=` on the screen command line. The `-p` option allows the preselection of a window, and `=` as the name of that window specifies the windowlist.

Comment: I'm not in need of this any more, so I'm not going to test it. But I trust you that it works so I'll accept it as the answer.